# WPF: Open and Close windows

Tags: c#, wpf, window, showdialog

I have two windows with WindowStyleset set a none, MainWindow and window1. I'd like to open window1 and close it when I click on a close button. Window1 is only used for configuration values.

I've tried with: In `MainWindow` I have a menu

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window1 secondWindow = new Window1();
    secondWindow.ShowDialog();
}
```

In Window1 close button code

```
private void btnQuit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();                
}
```

When I click on close button, the app is closed. If I change `ShowDialog()` for `Show()` the app is closed. How can I do it? I only want to close `window1` and stay in `MainWindow`?

Thank you!.

Comment: Is the `btnQuit_Click` handler in MainWindow or in Window1?

Comment: btnQuit_Click is in Window1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's related to which of the Windows that you have is the Main window of the application
try to set App.Current.MainWindow to your Main window like this

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        App.Current.MainWindow = this;
        Window1 secondWindow = new Window1();
        secondWindow.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Comment: I tried it but I can't close `window1`, I changed `btnQuit_click` with `App.Current.Windows[0].Close();` and added `App.Current.MainWindow = this;` in `MenuItem_Click`.

Comment: you can't close window1 or the app is close all!!

Comment: is there any way to do it? I only need a main window and another window to set some contiguration values.

Comment: please describe more .. when you close window1 what happens

Comment: if I add `App.Current.MainWindow = this;` in `MenuItem_Click` the app is close all.

Comment: @drsromero if I take your code as is and put it into a test application with a MainWindow and Window1 forms, it works. You are somehow closing down your MainWindow, I suspect there is code that is running that you are not showing us or you are getting an error which is terminating your program.

Comment: @Mark-Hall I had an error in my MenuItem Header I corrected it and now works!!
Thank you all!!!